# Why calls via CallKit and PushKit are displayed in 2-4 minutes after the device is rebooted?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

I found that if I restart the iPhone then calls through `CallKit` + `PushKit` start to show up in 2-4 minutes, I decided to test it on the famous messangers such as What's app and Telegram and they have exactly the same behavior. I want to know why so much time passes before receiving calls.

My devices are iPhone 6 and 7.